# how to get the location of the current file in revel

Tags: go, revel

I am using golang revel web framework and 
I am trying to create a `sqlite` db in the current working directory.

`model.go`

```
func New(dbName string,table string) *Db {
    _,filename,_,_ := runtime.Caller(1)
    db , err := sql.Open("sqlite3",path.Join(path.Dir(filename),dbName))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    database := &Db{Database:db}
    _,err = db.Exec("create table %s" +
    "( id integer primary key, " +
    "name varchar(100),"+
    "email varchar(100),"+
    "branch varchar(100),"+
    "help varchar(100)",)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

}

I have a test in place which just calls this function.

whenever i run the test using `revel test` or by going to the `localhost:9000/@tests`, the function `Panics` and the error message is
`cannot open the database file`.

The reason that is happening is because the `filename` returned by `runtime.Caller(1)` is `/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s` for which the program has no permission.

if i directly write `./foo.db`, even then the error shows.

I tried `os.Getwd()` which return empty string.

I also tried `filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))`
but that returned `/home/girish/GoProjects/bin/revel.d` which is the `revel` binary.

So whats the best way to find the directory of the `model.go`?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense to get the directory of the model.go file at runtime, because the compiled executable could be on a completely different filesystem.

You may want to get the directory of where the running executable was started from:

```
dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
```

dir will be the folder where the program lives at runtime.